# Comparing User Input From The Keyboard To A String Using A While Loop

Tags: java, string, input, comparison

I"m having problems trying to get my program to detect when the user enters Y for Yes and N for No.

**This Is the code...**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Examulator {
    public static void main (String [] args){

        System.out.println("How Many Marks Was Your Practicals Out Of?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int practicalsOutOf = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Okay And What Did You Get Out Of:" + "  " + practicalsOutOf);
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner (System.in);
        int whatYouGotInPracticals = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Okay so you got" + "  " + whatYouGotInPracticals + "/" + practicalsOutOf + "  " + "For Your Practicals Correct?");
        scan.nextLine();


        String answer = scan.nextLine();
        while ( !"Y".equals(answer) || !"N".equals(answer)){
            System.out.println("Please Type A Capital Y If Correct Or A Capital N If Incorrect");
            scan.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Thank You");


    }
}
```

When I type Y or N it's not recognising it as a correct answer the program continues to run through the look displaying:

**Please enter a Capital Y if correct or a capital N if Incorrect**

So it's not exiting the loop?

If I get rid of the OR comparison and just keep it so the program is only looking for the **Y** I can get the program to exit the loop if I type in the correct answer **first time** otherwise it ignores a correct answer and continues to run through the loop.

When I put the OR comparison back in so that the program can accept Y or N it won't accept any of them and will continue to run through the loop, even if I type in the correct answer first time.

I really can't see what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need multiple `Scanner`s?

Comment: I was using one scanner to scan for integers only and one to scan for strings only. I'm not sure if it was the right way to do it but it compiled and ran so I though it was okay? I've just started programming a week and a half ago so I'm a complete noob...still got a lot of learning to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` condition is not good:

```
!"Y".equals(answer) || !"N".equals(answer)
```

Means that:

If `answer` is **not** `"Y"` **or**  `answer` is **not** `"N"` you'll continue.

As `answer` can never be both (the only way to satisfy this condition) this will always be true.

Just change the `||` to `&&`.

And yes, there's no need to create another identical scanner.

**EDIT**:
Why `&&` works:

```
!"Y".equals(answer) && !"N".equals(answer)
```

Means that if `answer` is not `"Y"` **and** `answer` is not `"N"` meaning the user gave us some string that is neither `"Y"` nor `"N"`, which is a wrong input in our case we should ask him to try again.

Note that this condition is false if and only if `answer` is `"Y"` or `"N"`, which is exactly what we want.

**EDIT**:

The other problem is due to the fact that you never assign `answer` in the loop(so it will have the initial value forever *muhahaha* :) ), please see the DEMO below..

This: `scan.nextLine();` just scans and ignores the return value  this : `answer = scan.nextLine();` doesn't.

[DEMO.](http://ideone.com/jMKwgi) [DEMO2](http://ideone.com/81M6Tw)

Comment: Okay I think I see what your saying. But when I change it to && It works if I input the correct answer first time but If I enter say M by accident the program will say: Please Type A Capital Y If Correct Or A Capital N If Incorrect and will continue in this loop even if I eventually type Y or N. Also I though that && meant that the user would have to Type Y and N for the condition to be true? And with || the program would check the first condition (Y) and if it was correct it would Ignore the second conditionan continue? Same if firs condition was wrong it would move to the next condition?

Comment: @chriscoyle I've addressed the second issue as well, take a look at the edit. As far as the boolean condition on this one goes goes I'll add an explanation in a minute.

Comment: Ahhh lol I see what happened now! Just had a look at the demo it sorted the problem :D. I spent about 2 hours trying to get that to work :)). Was even considering turning my laptop off and on to see if it would fix it lol. Cheers Scis :D

Answer (score 0):

Try with;

```
String answer = scan.nextLine();
while ( !"Y".equals(answer) && !"N".equals(answer)){
    System.out.println("Please Type A Capital Y If Correct Or A Capital N If Incorrect");
    answer = scan.nextLine(); //here set the next scan to answer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't set answer inside the loop, you only set it once prior to the loop (thats why it works only the first time):

change

```
scan.nextLine();
```

to

```
answer = scan.nextLine();
```